# What is the proper encoding for a v4l device, what chromium can accept?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, camera, v4l

I use uv4l driver for Raspberry Pi Camera Module V2, which gives me the possibility to choose the encoding, framerate etc...

The following encodings were tested:
yuv420, nv21, yvu420, rgb565, rgb565x, bgr24, rgb24, rgba, bgra, mjpeg, jpeg, h264,
with the framerate of 30.
On all cases chromium prints the following into standard error, when it tries to access the device via WebRTC:

```
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(108)] Not implemented reached in void media::GetSupportedFormatsForV4L2BufferType(int, media::VideoCaptureFormats*)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(72)] Not implemented reached in std::list<float> media::GetFrameRateList(int, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(108)] Not implemented reached in void media::GetSupportedFormatsForV4L2BufferType(int, media::VideoCaptureFormats*)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(72)] Not implemented reached in std::list<float> media::GetFrameRateList(int, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(108)] Not implemented reached in void media::GetSupportedFormatsForV4L2BufferType(int, media::VideoCaptureFormats*)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(72)] Not implemented reached in std::list<float> media::GetFrameRateList(int, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(108)] Not implemented reached in void media::GetSupportedFormatsForV4L2BufferType(int, media::VideoCaptureFormats*)
[1113:1152:0701/090110:ERROR:video_capture_device_factory_linux.cc(72)] Not implemented reached in std::list<float> media::GetFrameRateList(int, uint32_t, uint32_t, uint32_t)
```

All possible configuration can be found here:
http://www.linux-projects.org/documentation/uv4l-raspicam/

Question:
What is the proper video stream (client side) what chromium can process.